# Under Fedora 31 All Java apps barely responsive until I open a dialog

Tags: fedora, java

I use a fair number of swing applications under fedora 31 (and 30 before it). Since fedora 30, I often find swing UIs, like in Intellij products, or DbVisualizer to be very, very unresponsive; almost to the point of unusability. As an example there may be several seconds delay between clicking on a treeview control and a node being selected.

This is my java version: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.5.10-0.fc31.x86_64.

I can always fix this by opening a ancillary dialog in the application: the activity monitor in the IDE, the settings window in DbVisualizer. Doing so makes the app work normally.

I'm curious as to whether this happens to anyone else, and whether there is something I can do to fix it. I've played around with different versions of the JDK. Lastly, this seems like a super strange behavior and an explanation would be nice too.